# Mongo aggregation and separating sub-objects into separate documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using the MongoDB aggregation framework to try and collect some totals from our dataset.

Here is an example of the source data:

```
{
    "urn": "urn:content:epi:0001",
    "duration": 3450272,
    "profiles": {
         "low": {
             "mp3": {
                 "size": 8623059425,
                 "url": "0001_low.mp3"
             },
             "oga": {
                 "size": 8623059425,
                 "url": "0001_low.oga"
             },
             "m4a": {
                 "size": 8623059425,
                 "url": "0001_low.m4a"
             }
         },
         "medium": {
             "mp3": {
                 "size": 8623059425,
                 "url": "0001_medium.mp3"
             },
             "oga": {
                 "size": 8623059425,
                 "url": "0001_medium.oga"
             },
             "m4a": {
                 "size": 8623059425,
                 "url": "0001_medium.m4a"
             }
         },
         "high": {
             "mp3": {
                 "size": 8623059425,
                 "url": "0001_high.mp3"
             },
             "oga": {
                 "size": 8623059425,
                 "url": "0001_high.oga"
             },
             "m4a": {
                 "size": 8623059425,
                 "url": "0001_high.m4a"
             }
         }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking to do is separate each `profile.(low|medium|high).(mp3|oga|m4a)` into a separate document/item for aggregation, so for example:

```
{
    "_id": null,
    "files": [
        {
            "urn": "urn:content:epi:0001",
            "duration": 3450272,
            "size": 8623059425,
            "url": "0001_low.mp3"
        },
        {
            "urn": "urn:content:epi:0001",
            "duration": 3450272,
            "size": 8623059425,
            "url": "0001_low.oga"
        },
        {
            "urn": "urn:content:epi:0001",
            "duration": 3450272,
            "size": 8623059425,
            "url": "0001_low.m4a"
        },
        {
            "urn": "urn:content:epi:0001",
            "duration": 3450272,
            "size": 8623059425,
            "url": "0001_medium.mp3"
        },
        {
            "urn": "urn:content:epi:0001",
            "duration": 3450272,
            "size": 8623059425,
            "url": "0001_medium.oga"
        },
        {
            "urn": "urn:content:epi:0001",
            "duration": 3450272,
            "size": 8623059425,
            "url": "0001_medium.m4a"
        },
        {
            "urn": "urn:content:epi:0001",
            "duration": 3450272,
            "size": 8623059425,
            "url": "0001_high.mp3"
        },
        {
            "urn": "urn:content:epi:0001",
            "duration": 3450272,
            "size": 8623059425,
            "url": "0001_high.oga"
        },
        {
            "urn": "urn:content:epi:0001",
            "duration": 3450272,
            "size": 8623059425,
            "url": "0001_high.m4a"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this sort of thing possible using the Aggregation Framework, or is this something on MapReduce can do?

Comment: What have you tried? It would be a lot simpler to achieve using the AF if the structure used arrays with properties like `fileType:"mp3"` rather than specific properties of `low : { "mp3" : ... }}`.

Comment: And, depending on how you're using the data, it would be easy to process on the client side into the structure you want (and likely just as efficiently).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to change the structure as it's already widely used by multiple areas of the system.
I agree that perhaps leaving some of the logic to the client instead of trying to do it all in the aggregation step is probably the way to go, and is actually what I have implemented at the moment.
I was just wondering if it was at all possible to do something like this all in the aggregation step :)

Comment: Honestly, it seems like a lot of busy work for the database server to perform just to flatten the structure and also it means that some of the data is repeatedly sent from the server (like `urn` and `duration`).

Comment: it is possible to do this with mapreduce...

Answer (score 0):

No, the aggregation framework's `$unwind` stage is the only way to turn a single collection document into multiple pipeline documents, and `$unwind` works only with arrays, not subdocuments like yours.